# Is there anything I can do to optimise this complex query?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, subquery

I have a rather complex query that spans several layers of subqueries, the two primary ones fetching data from the exact same fields, only one takes the values themselves, the other takes aggregates.

I use most of the values for the sake of creating values I mix to customise the ordering of the results. The results themselves are fetched based on a fulltext search, but to keep query times to acceptable levels I have to limit the inner queries, which cuts out many results that may be relevant, so I'd like to be able to keep this limit to higher values (if it can't be avoided at all).

This is by far the most complex query I've ever pieced together, so I'm by no means an expert, but I reached the limit of the rooms for optimisation I can see and would appreciate any help.

### DB Fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5742db7124a1dccaff7133d2e2b30b8d

### The query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(place_id) AS place_id,
       name,
       administration,
       country,
       MAX(relevance) AS relevance
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           (rescale(population, mn_pop, mx_pop)              * 2.4) +
           (rescale(name_relevance, mn_plre, mx_plre)        * 0.0) +
           (rescale(distance, mx_dist, mn_dist)              * 2.2) +  -- inverted
           if(t.country_id = (
               SELECT country_id FROM country_names
               WHERE name = 'Germany'
               LIMIT 1
           ), 0.6, 0)
               / 4
               AS relevance
    FROM (
        SELECT resl.*,
               MIN(aggr.population)             AS mn_pop,
               MAX(aggr.population)             AS mx_pop,
               MIN(aggr.name_relevance)         AS mn_plre,
               MAX(aggr.name_relevance)         AS mx_plre,
               MIN(aggr.distance)               AS mn_dist,
               MAX(aggr.distance)               AS mx_dist
        FROM (
            SELECT p.population,
                   ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(position, ST_POINTFROMTEXT(ST_ASTEXT(POINT(7.4653, 51.5136)), 4326)) AS distance,
                   MATCH(pn.name) AGAINST('+dor*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)     AS name_relevance
            FROM places p
            JOIN place_names pn ON p.id = pn.place_id
            JOIN admin_names an ON p.admin_id = an.admin_id
            JOIN country_names cn ON p.country_id = cn.country_id
            JOIN languages l ON pn.language_id = l.id AND an.language_id = l.id AND cn.language_id = l.id
            WHERE l.code_3 = 'ENG' AND MATCH(pn.name) AGAINST('+dor*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            LIMIT 200
        ) aggr
        JOIN (
            SELECT p.id AS place_id,
                   pn.name AS name,
                   an.name AS administration,
                   an.abbr AS admin_abbr,
                   cn.name AS country,
                   p.population AS population,
                   p.country_id AS country_id,
                   ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(position, ST_POINTFROMTEXT(ST_ASTEXT(POINT(7.4653, 51.5136)), 4326)) AS distance,
                   MATCH(pn.name) AGAINST('+rom*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)     AS name_relevance
            FROM places p
            JOIN place_names pn ON p.id = pn.place_id
            JOIN admin_names an ON p.admin_id = an.admin_id
            JOIN country_names cn ON p.country_id = cn.country_id
            JOIN languages l ON pn.language_id = l.id AND an.language_id = l.id AND cn.language_id = l.id
            WHERE l.code_3 = 'ENG' AND MATCH(pn.name) AGAINST('+dor*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            LIMIT 200
        ) resl
        GROUP BY place_id, resl.name, resl.administration, resl.admin_abbr, resl.country
    ) t
) t2
WHERE place_id is not null
GROUP BY country, administration, admin_abbr, name
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

(I removed parts of the query and columns that work the same way as others that I left in, for brevity. I'm sorry that there's still so much material but as mentioned, it's a complex query.)

As you can see, there are quite a few repeated or very similar lines between the two inner subqueries; that seems quite dirty and it suggests me that there is room for improvement (which may or may not also improve performance).

### `EXPLAIN`ed:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | 75 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 2 | DERIVED | <derived4> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 | 100 | NULL |
| 4 | DERIVED | <derived5> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 4 | DERIVED | <derived6> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 100 | Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 6 | DERIVED | l | NULL | const | PRIMARY,languages_code_3_uindex | languages_code_3_uindex | 12 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 6 | DERIVED | pn | NULL | fulltext | place_names_place_id_language_uindex,new_place_names_language_id_fk,place_id,place_name_fulltext | place_name_fulltext | 0 | const | 1 | 34.97 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
| 6 | DERIVED | p | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,admin_id,country_id | PRIMARY | 8 | geodb.pn.place_id | 1 | 100 | Using where |
| 6 | DERIVED | cn | NULL | eq_ref | admin_names_country_id_language_uindex,country_id,language_id | admin_names_country_id_language_uindex | 12 | geodb.p.country_id,const | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 6 | DERIVED | an | NULL | eq_ref | admin_names_admin_id_language_uindex,admin_id,language_id | admin_names_admin_id_language_uindex | 12 | geodb.p.admin_id,geodb.pn.language_id | 1 | 100 | Using index condition |
| 5 | DERIVED | l | NULL | const | PRIMARY,languages_code_3_uindex | languages_code_3_uindex | 12 | const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 5 | DERIVED | pn | NULL | fulltext | place_names_place_id_language_uindex,new_place_names_language_id_fk,place_id,place_name_fulltext | place_name_fulltext | 0 | const | 1 | 34.97 | Using where |
| 5 | DERIVED | p | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,admin_id,country_id | PRIMARY | 8 | geodb.pn.place_id | 1 | 100 | Using where |
| 5 | DERIVED | cn | NULL | eq_ref | admin_names_country_id_language_uindex,country_id,language_id | admin_names_country_id_language_uindex | 12 | geodb.p.country_id,const | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| 5 | DERIVED | an | NULL | eq_ref | admin_names_admin_id_language_uindex,admin_id,language_id | admin_names_admin_id_language_uindex | 12 | geodb.p.admin_id,geodb.pn.language_id | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 3 | SUBQUERY | country_names | NULL | ref | country_name,country_name_fulltext | country_name | 1020 | const | 1 | 100 | NULL |

### Summary:

1. Can this query be rewritten more elegantly/compactly?
2. Can the query be further optimised in any of its aspects?
3. Can the query be modified such that the inner `LIMIT` (in the example, 200) can be removed or increased as much as possible without having such averse effects on performance?

Comment: Can you please provide a **working** fiddle - I tried with your DDL/DML above and got [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa7636544239e22dfaae416b2193fa38)... Also, it would probably be best if you included **all** of the query and relevant data - *cf.* `(I removed parts of the query and columns that work the same way as others that I left in, for brevity. I'm sorry that there's still so much material but as mentioned, it's a complex query.)`...

Comment: @Vérace You appeared to have skipped a couple tables from the creation script; the order I put them in should satisfy all constraints.  The columns I removed from the query are still there in the tables I provided, I just don't select them in the query, but they aren't used in WHERE clauses or anywhere else anyway. I'll prepare a fiddle.

Comment: @Vérace I added a working dbfiddle to the question. However, the query is returning nothing there but I guarantee that on my database it does return some items. I'm not quite sure what could cause the difference.

Comment: Nevermind, I had forgotten the data for one of the tables, I'm so sorry. the fiddle is updated and works now.

Comment: I don't see the SELECT in the fiddle.

Comment: @RickJames It's in the last cell, starting with `SELECT MIN(place_id) AS place_id,
       name,
       administration,
       country,
       MAX(relevance) AS relevance`. I'm not very familiar with dbfiddle.uk, I hope we're not seeing different things with the same URL.

Comment: What table is `position` in??

Comment: Don't how much actual impact this makes, but one thing particularly stands out to me as redundant. The `aggr` derived table is cross-joined with the `resl` derived table, then the `aggr` columns are aggregated while the grouping is done by the `resl` columns.  That makes little sense.  Instead, you could aggregate the `aggr` rows separately, then cross-join the resulting single row with `resl` (obviously you wouldn't need to group anything at that point), see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4fc987841386c036521e867d3fbb79b0).

Comment: @AndriyM that simple change seems to speed up the query by (on average) at least half a second! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Where practical, measure the time taken for each subquery.  Then focus on the slowest subquery.

When a `SELECT` involve `JOINs` and a `LIMIT` (or a `GROUP BY`), an optimization is to turn it inside out.  I am referring to the two derived tables with `LIMIT 200`.  That is rewrite the subquery to find the ids of the 200 row as simply as possible, *then* `JOIN` to the other tables.

It is strange to have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  And, without knowing what table `position` is in, I can't get more specific.

Comment: `position` is in table `places`, as the creation script shows.

Comment: My issue with your suggestion is that I need the joins to find the IDs in the first place, because I need to restrict by language and then match `name`, `administration` etc, which all sit in different tables. Furthermore, I need both the records themselves and some aggregates (each one of the two inner queries); even if I got the IDs with a further subquery I would then have to copy this subquery twice to get both sets of results, right?
The reason I have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is that ordering all the results in the innermost subqueries takes a lot of time.